# How to remove footer in latex

Tags: header-footer

Please tell me how to remove footer from whole document in latex. I'm using `acmsmall` template. I used this but it only removed footer from first page.

```
\makeatletter
\def\runningfoot{\def\@runningfoot{}}
\def\firstfoot{\def\@firstfoot{}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: You should post a Minimal Working Example to help us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

`fancyhdr` package gives a lot of control. try for example

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
```